# How to use oembed Facebook

Tags: php, html, facebook, oembed

I'm trying to embed Facebook's posts (e.g. video) using oEmbed format. According to Facebook documentation, oEmbed is now supported. I'm trying this PHP code:

```
$json_post = @file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url={MY VIDEO URL HERE}');
$oembed = json_decode($json_post);
var_dump($oembed);
```

I already used the same code for Instagram with success, now I'm getting a NULL result. oEmbed works good if i directly write the URL on the browser. Am i missing something?
Thanks.

### Update

I tried with Curl:

```
$url='https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$page = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
print_r($page);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now i get:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   Location: https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser
>   access-control-allow-method: OPTIONS
>   Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-FB-Debug, X-Loader-Length
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.facebook.com
>   Vary: Origin
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   X-FB-Debug: gGcZzyllZadlcn/6jz2HqqouIcDnhTzxzR+etWXhZEnOcditfsaIUw0WjgO3nELHzveRCYa1UM86D3LA/nLnNw==
>   Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2017 10:18:47 GMT
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 0
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   X-XSS-Protection: 0
>   public-key-pins-report-only: max-age=500; pin-sha256="WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18="; pin-sha256="r/mIkG3eEpVdm+u/ko/cwxzOMo1bk4TyHIlByibiA5E="; pin-sha256="q4PO2G2cbkZhZ82+JgmRUyGMoAeozA+BSXVXQWB8XWQ="; report-uri="http://reports.fb.com/hpkp/"
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>   Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   X-FB-Debug: zwArox8KyM3BtwLymhiARCTltrrcE/pDqSWdqbHgstXVBEbIXG57Od2MfDnqgqSX5Tj43qoe8uYhphzwoZcXeg==
>   Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2017 10:18:48 GMT
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive

Still waiting for a reply.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the user agent with the curl and try,

```
$browser = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) \Chrome/24.0.1304.0 Safari/537.16';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser);
```

Here is the answer with file_get_content,

```
$options = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .  // check function.stream-context-create on php.net
                  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad 
      )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $json_post = @file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook%2Fvideos%2F10153231379946729%2F', false, $context);
    $oembed = json_decode($json_post);
    var_dump($oembed)
```